# Estimator of a Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, parameter-estimation

Given a random varable $Y$ where

$$
f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}e^{-(y-k)} \quad x>k\\0\quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
Given $n$ observations of $Y$. Is the sample mean $\bar{Y}$ an unbiased estimator of $k$? Is it a consistent estimator of $k$?

I have thought about it this way:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(\bar{Y}) &= \mathbb E\begin{bmatrix}\frac 1n \sum_i y_i\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\frac 1n \sum_i \mathbb E (y_i)
\end{align}
$$
Consider 
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(y_i) &= \int_k^\infty y e^{-(y-k)} dy\\
&=e^k\int_k^\infty y e^{-y} dy\\
&=-e^k[ye^{-y}+e^{-y}]^\infty_k\\
&=e^k(ke^k+e^{-k})\\
&= e^{2k}(k+1)
\end{align}
$$
and continuing
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(\bar{Y})
&=\frac 1n \sum_i \mathbb E (y_i)\\
&=\frac 1n (e^{2k})(k+1)\cdot n
&= (e^{2k})(k+1) \neq k
\end{align}
$$

and hence conclude that it is not a good estimator of $k$. However, since the value converges to a value as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we can say it is a consistent estimator.

### Update

As pointed out, $\mathbb E(y_i)=k+1$ and so $\mathbb E (\bar Y)=k+1$

Comment: You made a sign error calculating expectation of yi. It should end up being k+1. Notice this is exponential distribution shied to the right by k

Comment: Updated for mle.

Comment: See edit again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a sign error calculating expectation of $y_i$. It should end up being k+1. Notice this is exponential distribution shifted to the right by k.

It is obviously not consistent as it does not converge to k.

You can always subtract 1 from the mean to get an unbiased estimator, but this may be bigger than the minimum of your data, making it useless. The maximum likelihood estimator is minimum of $y_i$, if you are inerested.

It is consistent but biased. Write down the likelihood function and try it. Note the likelihood function should be written as

$e^{k-y}1_{y>k}$

[image]

Comment: Hello! I have just one more question for you. I have shown the $k+1$ portion and understood, but could you explain the minimum of $y_1$ part? I would say the minimum is still biased and not consistent, but comment that it is the MLE?

Comment: It is consistent but biased.

Comment: I am attempting to consider the pdf of the First Order Statistic which is $n[1-F_x(x)]^{n-1}f(x)$. Is that a way too?

Comment: @bryansis2010 i am a little confused what that is. I can put in a written answer if you want for the mle, if that is what you wanted.